# Why is my Neo4j database smaller in size compare to last week even though I have been adding nodes, relations and properties instead of removing them

Tags: neo4j, size, graph-databases

My database used to be like 80gb in size, now, after adding several million of nodes, its size is 35gb.

Any idea of what could have happened behind neo4j curtains that has considerably shrunk the database size?

This is the database's sysinfo:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's an article about [understanding Neo4j database growth](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/understanding-database-growth/) that should explain what you're seeing.

Summarized, when deletes happen, the entries in the relevant relationship and node store files are marked as deleted, but the storage isn't compressed (this would mess up our graph id numbering, since these act as pointers into our storage). We store `.id` files which track the ids that are eligible for reuse when data is added later. So upon mass node and relationship deletes, you would see the store size grow because 1. Stores are not being compressed to reclaim deleted item space and 2. Because we're adding to the reusable ids lists in the .id files.

When nodes and relationships are added later, the reusable ids are leveraged, and those places in the store files are reclaimed and used for the new nodes and relationships. The store files do not grow in space, but the reusable ids lists shrink, resulting in more storage space.

The other factor that may be involved here are [transaction logs](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/transaction-logs/) which are used as an interim transaction storage before the changes are flushed to the store. Rotation and retention policies may keep transaction files around for longer than you need them (please adjust the rotation and retention settings if you want to change that, do not modify or delete the transaction logs yourself). Transaction logs can typically take up a lot of room, so if you passed a point where a good portion of transaction logs could be pruned, then that may explain the space differences.

Comment: I think in my case the transaction logs were taking the extra space I've mentioned, because since I created this database, I haven't deleted any single node, just added million of them.

my configuration is: dbms.tx_log.rotation.retention_policy=1 days, according to the documentation, that means that the logs will be deleted after 1 day, correct?

Comment: That means we will keep transaction logs which contain any transaction committed in the last 24 hours. It will not delete all transaction logs every 24 hours.